# Rails form: How to restrict number of characters (digits) in input field

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, devise

In my devise registration form, I added a new field that needs to take upto 12 digits. To prevent non-digits from being entered, I have used the jquery solution from question 8481132 and it works.

For restricting to 12 digits, I used maxlength as follows:

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :vat_no, "VAT" %><br/>
    <%= f.number_field :vat_no, :maxlength => 12 %>
</div>
```

The generated html is

```
<div class="field">
    <label for="user_vat_no">VAT</label><br>
    <input maxlength="12" size="12" type="number" value="" name="user[vat_no]" id="user_vat_no">
</div>
```

Looks ok. But my browser (Safari on MacBook) is happily allowing any number of digits.

Comment: Check http://caniuse.com/ to determine if that attribute can be used for the os version you're using. You may need to create a js function to restrict the number of characters entered.

Comment: which safari version are you using? according to this it was fixed in 9 -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27319642/is-there-a-workaround-for-text-input-maxlength-not-working-in-safari

Comment: @Tasos My Safari version is 9.0.3

Comment: I went with writing a JQuery function as given in question [27319642](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27319642/is-there-a-workaround-for-text-input-maxlength-not-working-in-safari?)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/number_field_tag) page. Instead of `:maxlength => 12`, you could do:

```
<%= f.number_field :vat_no, :max => 999999999999, :min => -999999999999 %>
```

...since 999999999999 is the highest 12-digit number and -999999999999 is the lowest.